# Accessing elements in std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<Type>>

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to do some work with a vector of reference_wrappers, and running into some issues. Here's what I got:

```
std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<Type>> vec;
//Some stuff...
for(int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++)
{
        if(&vec[i] == &vec)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

This is not working. I am completely new to std::reference_wrapper, so I guess I'm not sure how to work with it. This above example gives me a 'lacks a cast' error.

I have another spot where I do something like:

`vec[i].someMethod();`

Which yields:

```
__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<std::reference_wrapper<Type> > >::value_type’ has no member named 'someMethod()'
```

I'm using GCC4.8

Comment: What is that for loop trying to accomplish?

Comment: That should be `vec[i].get().someMethod();` since there is no implicit conversion to `T&`.

Comment: I see @VladfromMoscow is just friendly here as he other places.

Comment: You're checking each member of the vector, to see if it happens to be the vector?

Comment: Time to show us a [testcase](http://sscce.org)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: Coming from you...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some simple example

```
int i = 10;
std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<int>> v;

v.push_back( std::ref( i ) );

std::cout << v[0] << std::endl;
std::cout << v[0].get() << std::endl;
```

In your case the construction will look as

```
vec[i].get().someMethod();
```

P.S. I did not look through your updated post.

Comment: This did it. Wasn't aware of the .get() method to retrieve data.

Comment: I would like to append that statement std::cout << v[0] << std::endl; in the example is valid due to std::reference_wrapper has a conversion operator operator T& () const noexcept;